# Firefox options are seems ignored when configuring through desired capabilities?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

My idea here is to set marionette verbosity to OFF!! it's working when

```
FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
ffOptions.setLogLevel(Level.OFF);               
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOptions);
```

but for the following case, it's failed to set verbosity to OFF

```
FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
ffOptions.setLogLevel(Level.OFF); 
DesiredCapabilities ffCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
ffCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile());
ffCapabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", ffOptions);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffCapabilities);
```

Firefox profile object

```
protected FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile() {
        FirefoxProfile fxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        fxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
        fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
//FYI: this is working fine            
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", System.getProperty("user.dir") + ConfigCore.instance().downloadsDirectory());
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "text/csv,application/csv,application/text");
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv,application/csv,application/text");
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.animateNotifications", false);
            fxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
            return fxProfile;
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in `ffCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile());`? Where is the `firefoxProfile()` object?

Comment: Included firefoxprofile object!!

Comment: What difference happens between the two? Can you show some logs

Comment: first one doesn't have any desired capabilities configured!!