# How to decrease verbosity of Gecko Driver's logs?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, gecko

I've got strange logs (not sure if it's Gecko Driver's) when I start the minimal Selenium test. How disable these logs  out how to fix these problems?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriverLogLevel;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

public class ffruntest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.FATAL);

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
1546245354514   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1546245354514   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
dec 31, 2018 11:35:57 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[Child 13180, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 13180, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Parent 8104, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 21768, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 21768, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[RDD 28500, Chrome_ChildThrJavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm, line 409: Error: OS.File has been shut down. Rejecting post to remove
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm, line 409: Error: OS.File has been shut down. Rejecting post to remove
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.jsm, line 841: Error: Connection is not open.
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/IndexedDB.jsm, line 349: UnknownError: The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, I've already used FF options like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002918/how-to-set-verbosity-of-marionette-driver), and it helped to  remove something, but not everything.

- FireFox 65.0b7 (64-bit), no active plugins, no addons
- geckodriver 0.23.0 (2018-10-04)
- selenium 3.14.0

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox (and geckodriver) you can try either of the following:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.logfile", "/dev/null");`

or running the test with the command line param `-Dwebdriver.firefox.logfile=/dev/null`

If you are running this on Windows, then chose a suitable file location in place of `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set them to false.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "false");
```

or you can redirect the logs

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", logsPath());
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't helps a lot. Logs are still exist.